# CA1707 warning on constants names

Tags: visual-studio, code-analysis, fxcop, roslyn-code-analysis

why microsoft keeps documenting code with constant like WM_SOMECONSTANT but the code analysis in Visual Studio reports the CA1707 warning?

Should we suppress all these warning for the solution?
should we rename all the constants?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're referencing a Native function in Windows. The recommendation here is to put the call to that function  (and any enums and constants it needs) in a separate `NativeMethods` class with its own `.cs` file. That way it's easy to suppress the `CA1707` in code for the whole file.

And it's recommended to not sprinkle your non-native code with all of these constants either, can you create a simple wrapper that acts as the bridge between the ugly native win32 API and how you intend people to use it in your C# app? That way the rest of the code can remain blissfully unaware of it.

A few tricks that may help here:

- When using the new `.editorconfig` style ruleset files, you can [specify a naming convention for the files to which rules apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2019&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#generated-code):

  ```
  [*.{cs,vb}]
  dotnet_diagnostic.CA1707.severity = warning

  [NativeMethods.{cs,vb}]
  dotnet_diagnostic.CA1707.severity = none
  ```
- You can suppress inline with a compiler directive for a whole file:

  ```
  #pragma warning disable CA1707 // Identifiers should not contain underscores

  public class Class1
  {
      public string WM_ERSHSERHSEHRSER;
  }

  #pragma warning restore CA1707 // Identifiers should not contain underscores
  ```
- You could move the native methods to a separate class library and disable the rule there altogether.